Does std::steady_clock::now() make a syscall in Linux?
My project is a long time daemon service and need to busy check some conditions and take actions as soon as possible.
I want to use std::steady_clock to account the responsing time of my service and the busy/free duty proportion.
Everytime the service runs about in 20~100 microseconds, while the designing requirement is less than 160us. So I'm afraid that it would waste too much time to call steady_clock::now() frequently.
My question:

Does steady_clock::now() make a syscall potentially? Would it
result my program to be blocked irregularly for a long time(exceed
1ms)?
Is there any better alternative method?


This is likely to depend on specifics of kernel and library version, as well as hardware architecture.

If you want to know what's actually going on, then 1) read the source code. 2) use a profiler. 3) use a debugger.   But, if I were to guess, I'd guess that on linux the gettimeofday or similar syscall would be called using the vdso, so would stay entirely in userspace - but that's just a guess.

Looks like it can: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/chrono.cc#L52

"need to busy check some conditions and take actions" - why use a busy loop and not a condition variable?

@JesperJuhl I have tested the performance of busy checking and of conditional var. The former needs about 90ns to check a atomic var, while the latter needs 2400ns on my PC.

@Leon Was that with code build with optimization enabled? Something like -O3 -flto? Also, even if the busy looping can react faster, have you considered the (potentially massive) extra cost in electricity and cores being tied up that could be used for other purposes?

@leon yeah, having a "long time daemon service" is sure to be great when it's cooking your CPU at 100% all the time... well, it's not my project.

I would try nanosleep with a real-time scheduler.
